# Numerical Optimization Using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have written a python code to control a nonlinear dynamical system using Nonlinear Model Predictive Control (NMPC) and therefore, I should solve a nonlinear minimization problem in each time step. Following are some parts of the code developed for this problem.

```
def objective_function(self, U_pred, X_curr):
        U_p = np.reshape(U_pred, (self.n_inputs, self.Nu))
        cost1 = self.stage_cost(X_curr)
        
        for i in range(self.Nu):
            u = np.reshape(U_p[:,i], (self.n_inputs, 1))
            X_new = Plant.solver(X_curr, self.U_prev, u, self.dt, 3)
            cost1 += self.stage_cost(X_new)
            X_curr = X_new
        return cost1 

def stage_cost(self, X):
        Error = np.array(X, dtype=np.float32) - np.array(self.Xd, dtype=np.float32)
        er = (Error[0] ** 2) + (Error[1] ** 2)
        return er.item()
        


def solver(self, X0, U_old, U_new, dt, n_elements):
        t = np.linspace(0, dt, n_elements)
        sol = odeint(self.equations_of_motion, X0, t, args=(U_old, U_new, dt/(n_elements-1)))
        X_final = sol[n_elements-1,:]
        return X_final


def feedback_control(self, X_curr):
        res = minimize(self.objective_function, self.last_U_pred, method='SLSQP',
               args=(X_curr), options={'xatol': 1e-8, 'disp': False}, bounds=[(-500,500)] * (self.n_inputs * self.Nu))

        U_pred = res.x
        u_feedback = U_pred[0:self.n_inputs]
        u_feedback = np.reshape(u_feedback, (self.n_inputs, 1))
        self.U_prev = u_feedback
        
        return u_feedback
```

Where these functions are the methods of two different classes "Plant Class" and "NMPC Class".

However, the solution of the minimization problem is always equal to the initial guess (X0) that has been selected to be [0,0,0,0].

I checked all the objective_function(), stage_cost() and solver() functions separately that their outputs is rational and physically meaningful. The output of the objective_function() is also a non-negative scalar.

Could anyone please help me about this issue.
Thank you.
Regards,
Mahmood

Comment: How are these actually invoked? This doesn't quite seem reproducible